# window.screen.width value not changing in iPad browsers when screen orientation changed

Tags: javascript, html, ipad

I'm trying to get the screen width of user device using `window.screen.width`. This method is working fine on most of the devices but not on iPad. When the iPad is in portrait mode, the screen width is shown to be 768px and height to be 1024px(using `window.screen.height`).All good till now. But the width and height remains the same in landscape mode too. In other devices, the "**width*height**" value switches when orientation changes and all my calculations was based on that concept.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of using screen.width use the below one:

```
var body = document.body;

    if(body.scrollWidth < 1024){
      //code here
    }

    if(body.scrollWidth < 768){
      //code here
    }

    if(body.scrollWidth == 1024){
      //code here
    }

    if(body.scrollWidth <= 1024){
      //code here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution using

```
window.innerWidth 
window.innerHeight
```

will work perfect if your webview fill you ios ViewController
and will give you correct values even when you change the orientation while application is running..

That `screen.availWidth & screen.availHeight`  give you the correct values only at first run before change the iPad orientation